# Flattening 1-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My current schema looks like this:

```
PersonType (PersonTypeID, Name, Description)

Person (PersonID,PersonTypeID, FirstName, ... )

PersonDynamicField (PersonDynamicFieldID, PersonTypeID, Name, Description, DataType, DefaultValue, ...)

PersonDynamicFieldValue (PersonDynamicFieldValueID, PersonDynamicFieldID, PersonID, Value, ...)
```

That is, a person is of a certain type. For example, Customer. For each `PersonType`, there can dynamically be added additional fields to store about a PersonType. For a Customer, we might want to add fields to PersonDynamicField such as LikesChocolate, FavoriteColor, HappinessScale, etc. The value for those fields would then be stored in PersonDynamicFieldValue.

I hope my writing makes sense.

What I would like to do, is a query that can flatten this structure and return a result looking like this:

```
PersonID, PersonTypeID, FirstName, LikesChocolate, FavoriteColor, HappinessScale
1, 2, Robert, 1, Green, 9
2, 2, John, 0, Orange, 5
...
```

I'm kind of stuck and don't really know where to even start.

Can you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get the result that you want there are several ways that you can convert the rows of data into columns.

Starting in SQL Server 2005, you can use the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function.  The basic structure of the code will be:

```
SELECT personid, persontypeid, firstname,[FavoriteColor],[HappinessScale],[LikesChocolate] 
from 
( 
  select p.personid, p.persontypeid, p.firstname, f.name fields, v.value 
  from person p 
  inner join persontype pt 
    on p.persontypeid = pt.persontypeid 
  left join PersonDynamicField f 
    on p.PersonTypeID = f.PersonTypeID 
  left join PersonDynamicFieldValue v 
    on f.PersonDynamicFieldID = v.PersonDynamicFieldID 
    and p.personid = v.personid 
) x 
pivot 
( 
  max(value) 
  for fields in ([FavoriteColor],[HappinessScale],[LikesChocolate]) 
) p;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93331/4).  The one issue that you are going to have with PIVOT is that it requires that the values being converted to columns are known at run-time.  For your situation, this seems impossible since the values can change.  As a result, you will have to use dynamic SQL to get the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Name) 
                    from PersonDynamicField
                    where PersonTypeID = 2
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT personid, persontypeid, firstname,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
               select p.personid,
                p.persontypeid,
                p.firstname,
                f.name fields,
                v.value
              from person p
              inner join persontype pt
                on p.persontypeid = pt.persontypeid
              left join PersonDynamicField f
                on p.PersonTypeID = f.PersonTypeID
              left join PersonDynamicFieldValue v
                on f.PersonDynamicFieldID = v.PersonDynamicFieldID
                and p.personid = v.personid
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for fields in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93331/5). These will give a result:

```
| PERSONID | PERSONTYPEID | FIRSTNAME | FAVORITECOLOR | HAPPINESSSCALE | LIKESCHOCOLATE |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        1 |            2 |    Robert |         Green |              9 |              1 |
|        2 |            2 |      John |        Orange |              5 |              0 |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @bluefeet. That's the feature I was looking for and does what I need. Just one thing... could you explain briefly the statement starting with "Select @cols..."? I know what it does, but don't quite understand how. Thank you.

Comment: @Rob That is generating the list of distinct field names for each person type id.  When using a PIVOT, the columns must be known at run-time, so that line of code is creating a list of the columns names.

Answer (score -2):

What you want is commonly called a **pivot** and SQL Server has an operation that may help. Take a look at this article on MSDN for examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx